# Powershell script is executing but not working

Tags: powershell, sql-agent-job

I have a Powershell script which is running fine in Windows power shell IDE. But when I am running it from SQL agent job it is running with no error but it isn't doing any operation. Below is the message which I am getting in job history

```
     Executed as user: SERVER\SYSTEM. The string starting:  At line:1 
    char:1  +  <<<< "D:\FOLDER\POWERSCRIPT.ps1?  is missing the terminator: ". 
     At line:1 char:23  + "D:\FOLDER\POWERSCRIPT.ps1? <<<<      
     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (D:\FOLDER\POWERSCRIPT.ps1?:String) [],       ParentContainsErrorRecordException     
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.
```

Though, I have ran it from service account which is "DOMAIN\SERVICEACCOUNT" but it showing me "SERVERNAME**SYSTEM**

Let me know if more details is required.

**Edit- Script of Job**

```
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'MYJOB', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'DOMAIN\SERVICEAACCOUNT', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [RUN MONITOR]    Script Date: 5/15/2015 11:01:29 AM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'RUN MONITOR', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
        @command=N'powershell “D:\FOLDER\POWERSCRIPT.ps1″', 
        @flags=0
```

Comment: This might be a problem with the SQL Agent job definition rather than the powershell. The error suggests to me a problem with the string that tells the job where to find the Powershell script. Can you post the script for the agent job step?

Comment: @ChrisFlynn I have added script to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@command=N'powershell “D:\FOLDER\POWERSCRIPT.ps1″',
```

The quote marks here don't look right. You should remove them and re-type them as double-quote marks, like this:

```
@command=N'powershell "D:\FOLDER\POWERSCRIPT.ps1"',
```

Can you see the difference? This sometimes occurs when copying and pasting values.

Comment: +1 That works. But do you have any idea why it is not executing as  service account SERVERName\SYSTEM. Due to this I am not able to run my powershell script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure. However, the following documentation might help; there is a parameter for @@database_user_name on sp_add_jobstep. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187358.aspx. The parameter, and also @@owner_login_name, have some dependencies on sysadmin and database users, so maybe that'll help you? (Note double-@ otherwise SO thinks I'm tagging a user)